# Node and Express, getting all (custom) methods with .all()

Tags: node.js, curl, express

In Node and Express, I'm trying to get all traffic sent to a URL like this.

```
APP.all('/testCase', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Im called with the method: ' + req.method);
});
```

If I now do:
`curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/testCase` it works fine, I get the response: `Im called with the method: GET`

But when I do:
`curl -X INSERT http://localhost:3000/testCase` I'm getting: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

What Am I doing wrong? I will have many custom methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INSERT method is not supported by the node http parser. To see a list of the HTTP methods supported, you can run `node -pe "require('http').METHODS"`. In order to support custom HTTP methods, one would have to patch core itself (specifically the http parser).

Comment: Awesome, I've made a core mistake in understanding the methods, did some research related to your answer and now I understand them better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
app.all(path, callback [, callback ...])
```

> This method is like the standard app.METHOD() methods, except it
>   matches all HTTP verbs.
>
> It’s useful for mapping “global” logic for specific path prefixes or
>   arbitrary matches. For example, if you put the following at the top of
>   all other route definitions, it requires that all routes from that
>   point on require authentication, and automatically load a user. Keep
>   in mind that these callbacks do not have to act as end-points:
>   loadUser can perform a task, then call next() to continue matching
>   subsequent routes.

The most commons [HTTP methods](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) is:

- GET
- HEAD
- POST
- PUT
- DELETE
- TRACE
- CONNECT